# Json.Net: JSchema to Jtoken conversion issue

Tags: c#, json.net

Here is the little snippet:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JSchema> pair in dict)
{
    JToken token = pair.Value;
    string path = token.Path;
    ...       
}
```

JSchema class v2.0.0.0 contains implicit operator that provides simple conversion of types.

```
public static implicit operator JToken (
    JSchema s
)
```

JSchema object may contains something like this:

```
{
  "title": "Массив предупреждений",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "title": "Предупреждение",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "title": "Уникальный идентификатор предупреждения",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "element": {
        "title": "Идентификатор атрибута данных",
        "description": "Идентификатор атрибута данных в запросе, с которым связано предупреждение, может отсутствовать, если такая связь не установлена.",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "title": {
        "title": "Заголовок или название предупреждения",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "description": {
        "title": "Описание или полный текст предупреждения",
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "id",
      "title"
    ]
  }
}
```

But token variable is always {} (empty). What is wrong?

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do and provide further background?

Comment: I need to read a Path property from JSchema obj. But it is internal in JSchema class. So I'm trying to get JToken object with public Path property.

Comment: Can you show us what Jschema object contains?

Comment: Sure. Please, look at edited post.

Answer (score 1):

I also thought that the `JToken` conversion would treat a JSON schema as a JSON object. Since every JSON schema is itself JSON, that usage makes sense to us.

However, [the implementation](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/JSchema.cs#L398) clearly indicates that the conversion to `JToken` actually creates a *new* JSON object that is associated with the current schema. Similarly, the conversion from `JToken` accesses that associated schema.

Personally, I find this use of casts confusing.

We can work around it by re-parsing the schema as plain JSON:

```
var json = JObject.Parse(schema.ToString());
```